# Nodejs Server crashes after logging in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis

After logging in into the server the node server crashes with the error message

TypeError: Invalid argument type
at encodeCommand (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/RESP2/encoder.js:17:19)
at RedisCommandsQueue.getCommandToSend (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/commands-queue.js:187:45)
at Commander._RedisClient_tick (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:440:76)
at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:424:82)
at Commander.commandsExecutor (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:170:154)
at Commander.BaseClass. [as set] (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
at /Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/src/services/user.service.ts:46:15
at Generator.next ()
at /Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/chat/src/services/user.service.ts:8:71
at new Promise ()
[ERROR] 11:02:49 TypeError: Invalid argument type

Here is my authController.ts

```
import config from "config";
import { CookieOptions, NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { CreateUserInput, LoginUserInput } from "../schema/user.schema";
import { createUser, findUser, signToken } from "../services/user.service";
import AppError from "../utils/appError";

// Exclude this fields from the response
export const excludedFields = ["password"];

// Cookie options
const accessTokenCookieOptions: CookieOptions = {
  expires: new Date(
    Date.now() + config.get<number>("accessTokenExpiresIn") * 60 * 1000
  ),
  maxAge: config.get<number>("accessTokenExpiresIn") * 60 * 1000,
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: "lax",
};

// Only set secure to true in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
  accessTokenCookieOptions.secure = true;

export const registerHandler = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, CreateUserInput>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const user = await createUser({
      email: req.body.email,
      name: req.body.name,
      password: req.body.password,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        user,
      },
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    if (err.code === 11000) {
      return res.status(409).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "Email already exist",
      });
    }
    next(err);
  }
};

export const loginHandler = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, LoginUserInput>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    // Get the user from the collection
    const user = await findUser({ email: req.body.email });

    // Check if user exist and password is correct
    if (
      !user ||
      !(

await user.comparePasswords(user.password, req.body.password))

) {
  return next(new AppError("Invalid email or password", 401));
}

// Create an Access Token
const accessToken = await signToken(user);

// Send Access Token in Cookie
res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, accessTokenCookieOptions);
res.cookie("logged_in", true, {
  ...accessTokenCookieOptions,
  httpOnly: false,
});

    // Send Access Token
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      accessToken,
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Here is my userService.ts

```
import { omit, get } from 'lodash';
import { FilterQuery, QueryOptions } from 'mongoose';
import config from 'config';
import userModel, { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { excludedFields } from '../controllers/auth.controller';
import { signJwt } from '../utils/jwt';
import redisClient from '../utils/connectRedis';
import { DocumentType } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

// CreateUser service
export const createUser = async (input: Partial<User>) => {
  const user = await userModel.create(input);
  return omit(user.toJSON(), excludedFields);
};

// Find User by Id
export const findUserById = async (id: string) => {
  const user = await userModel.findById(id).lean();
  return omit(user, excludedFields);
};

// Find All users
export const findAllUsers = async () => {
  return await userModel.find();
};

// Find one user by any fields
export const findUser = async (
  query: FilterQuery<User>,
  options: QueryOptions = {}
) => {
  return await userModel.findOne(query, {}, options).select('+password');
};

// Sign Token
export const signToken = async (user: DocumentType<User>) => {
  // Sign the access token
  const access_token = signJwt(
    { sub: user._id },
    {
      expiresIn: `${config.get<number>('accessTokenExpiresIn')}m`,
    }
  );

  // Create a Session
  redisClient.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user), {
    EX: 60 * 60,
  });

  // Return access token
  return {access_token} ;
};
```

When logging in from postman the application gives token and then it gives error as a type error: Invalid argument type.
I have used docker and redis.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using MongoDB? Because it seems like you are trying to save a DocumentType in Redis.  Redis only accepts String inputs. Try converting the ID of the user to a string.

Comment: Also `user._id` is usually an `ObjectID`